# How to get tooltip to display using bootstrap after user selects text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to get a tooltip to show after the user selects some text.  After a few clicks within the appropriate div, I'm finding the order in which the tooltip appears gets reversed as it sometime shows without any content being selected.  Any advice on how to fix this?

```
 <script>
$('.test').click(function (e) {
    console.log('click');

    // RETURN HTML OF SELECTION    
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } 

    else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }

    console.log(html);

    if (html == "") {}
    else {

        console.log('right before popover');
        $(".test").popover();
        html = "";
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: @roasted I haven't made one before and I keep getting an error.  http://jsfiddle.net/xJ5Wf/2/  I'm using bootstrap and jquery